# Pythonic way to name derived classes

Tags: naming-conventions, python

I can't figure out what is the more acceptable naming convention for derived 
classes. Let's say we have a base class `Fruit`, from which we derive, classes for apple, 
orange and passion fruit. It is a concensus that the name of the base class should appear in the 
derived ones, but should it appear in the beginning of the class name or at the end?

Which is more Pythonic: `FruitApple`, `FruitOrange` and `FruitPassionFruit` or `AppleFruit`, 
`OrangeFruit` and `PassionFruitFruit`?

Comment: "It is a concensus that the name of the base class should appear in the derived ones ..." - really? It makes sense in many cases, sure, but I don't think it's imperative. The `Fruit` in `AppleFruit` doesn't add any information. The `FruitPassionFruit` is particular atrocious. Also, you can only take this so far in larger hierarchies. You don't include `object` in all your class names, do you?

Comment: Maybe others will disagree, but I would just go with `Apple`, `Orange`, and `PassionFruit`.  The purpose of the name of the class is to give an idea of what it does, not to list implementation details.  Besides, if you decided that `OrangeFruit` should derive from `CitrusFruit`, you wouldn't want to have to rename it to `OrangeCitrusFruit` everywhere.

Comment: Do you really think [`gtk.ColorSelectionDialog`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcolorselectiondialog.html) should be renamed to `gtk.ColorSelectionDialogWindowBinContainerWidgetObject`? :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Non! `ObjectWidgetContainerBinWindowDialogSelectionColor` sounds *so* much better!

Comment: The ``Fruit`` in ``AppleFruit`` may seem to add no information but I presume your real use case doesn't involve fruit and that multiple class hierarchies may need to exist side-by-side. :-)  Sometimes toy examples don't lead to good general purpose rules that apply to more complex software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use common sense.

In your example,  as others have discussed, the `Fruit` part is obviously redundant. Use just `Apple`, `Orange`, etc. Let's consider use another example instead.

If I had a base class called `Plugin`, I would name the derived class `FormattingPlugin`, which I read as “plugin that does formatting”. The alternative, `PluginFormatting`, reads as “formatting of plugins”. I guess the reading is subjective, so use your own best judgment.
But don't name it just `Formatting`, because, unlike in the fruits example, that's not a complete enough description of what the class does.

Answer (score 4):

"Concensus" is an elusive concept.  What you can do though is look to naming conventions used in the standard library to get a sense of what is the norm within the Python community.

For example, here's one extensive list of related classes and subclasses:  http://docs.python.org/library/internet.html

In the end though, it is a matter of taste guided by the principle that class names which are the clearest to the user are the best names.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific example you list above, everyone knows these things are fruits, so I think it is unnecessary to include `Fruit` in the subclass names.

More generally, whatever you chose is fine as long as it is consistent.

I tend to like the French way of naming the object first and descriptors (adjectives) afterwards, so if I had to choose, I would prefer `FruitApple`, `FruitOrange`, etc. over `AppleFruit`, `OrangeFruit` (and the redundant `PassionFruitFruit` :)). It also has the advantage of showing all the subclasses in a cluster when listed alphabetically, which might help some IDEs or code completers.

If, on the other hand, you take the standard library as the model, you'll find a preference for naming subclasses in `SpecificBase` format. For example, the logging module defines `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler` as subclasses of `Handler`.

Comment: The flip side of showing all the subclasses is that you have to type more until the name is unique and you can tab-complete it.